# symfony2 create database error

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to create my DB with Symfony2. I typed the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:create:database
```

The result is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'development'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

my `app/config/parameters.yml` file is:

```
{ parameters: {
     database_driver: pdo_mysql,
     database_host: 127.0.0.1,
     database_port: '3306',
     database_name: sf1,
     database_user: root,
     database_password: admin12345,
     mailer_transport: smtp,
     mailer_host: 127.0.0.1,
     mailer_user: null,
     mailer_password: null,
     locale: en,
     secret: 71f83dd18448f2f6300f90c60b4857933f32f2cd,
     database_path: null
      }
      }
```

Comment: Judging by the error message, the config you show here can't possibly be the same one that is used by `app/console`. That, or you haven't cleared your cache (`app/console cache:clear`)

Comment: that's mean your conf is overwritten somewhere

Comment: what is the doctrine configuration looks like in app/config/config.yml ?

Comment: and you can connect with these credentials via commandline ?